# Cast in lambda expression performance

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to cast in lambda expression
which one faster?

```
  var callObject = CallObjectHolder.Instance.Get(x => x.Log.Id.ToString() ==  ev.src_unique_id);
```

or

```
   var callObject = CallObjectHolder.Instance.Get(x => x.Log.Id == System.Convert.ToDouble(ev.src_unique_id)
);
```

Comment: You've written the code both ways. If you want to know which one is faster, *run them both and then you'll know*. If you had two horses and wanted to know which was faster, would you show pictures of the horses to strangers on the internet and have them guess, or would you race them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what's happening with the expression.

If you are making a call against a database so that the expression is translated into SQL, then the second method will be faster as it will only do the conversion once instead of converting every value in the table.

If you are querying data that are in memory, then they would perform roughly the same.

What worries me a bit though, is that it looks like you are using a floating point number as identifier, which would give you precision problems at some point. Floating point numbers are not designed to represent all numbers exactly, and comparing floating point numbers for equality should generally be avoided.

Comment: You should make that last paragraph **bold** ;p

Comment: I might add that the first method cancels the use of any database index. And I wish I could upvote the two parts of your answer separately!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to convert your string into a double `once` before the comparison loop.

Comment: What makes you think there's a loop?

Comment: It's a lambda expression, it's intent is to be executed on every object x until one is found that fits the expression. That gets really hard without some kind of loop. At least it's executed once per x, even if it's unrolled manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add my 2 cents here. When a value type is boxed, a new object must be allocated and constructed when a cast a value type to reference type. String is a reference type and you're converting value type to a reference type so the cost of boxing is involved. Unboxing is somewhat less costly as your object is already have memory allocated and you just have to get the value from heap and put it to the stack of value type.

Rest @Guffa already clarifies the comparison operator selection and cost.

Comment: When converting a number to a string an object is created, but it's not because of boxing. The object is the string that is the result of the conversion.